# Serialize from a Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I'm migrating a tradicional django-site to a API Restful.

I have a large form already working. This form is currently a *Django.forms.Form* object, and I want to send it's submit to a rest API point.

I want to do some similar to [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) but from the Form object instead a Model.

This project has some forms (not model based) and I want to reuse this code.

Regrettably I don't found how to do a serializer directly from Form.

#### Example I want to do

```
class LargeAndUgglyForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': _('Correo electrónico')}))

    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': _(u'Contraseña')}))

    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': _(u'Repetir contraseña')}))

    name_company = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': _('Nombre de la Empresa')}))

    # ... and much more fields


class SignupSerializer(???):
    Meta:
        form = LargeAndUgglyForm

    def create(self, validated_data):

        form_instance = LargeAndUgglyForm(validated_data)

        if form_instance.is_valid():
            # ...
```

PS. Sorry my english

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I received a response from a friend, and he gave me it:

https://django-rest-framework-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#formserializer

Comment: Please don't answer with a link only, as it might disappear in the future. You should include the key information directly in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer