# Serializing a Django form using django-rest-framework-braces

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have written a form in Django and I want to pass this form to my front-end client in JSON format. I am using django-rest-framework to serialize my models but I do not know how I can serialize my form with this framework. I have found https://django-rest-framework-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#forms as the solution in here: [Serialize from a Django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314697/serialize-from-a-django-form), but I do not know how to use the package to get the JSON formatted form out of it.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks,